# MySQL AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER to increase count

Tags: mysql, triggers

Any ideas what's wrong with this query? I searched around stackoverflow and it seems everyone is using this and it works.

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_entry 
    -> AFTER UPDATE ON entry FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     UPDATE entry 
    ->     SET count = count +1 
    ->     WHERE id = NEW.id
    -> END;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this first to change the delimiter

```
DELIMITER //
```

create the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_entry 
AFTER UPDATE ON entry FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE entry 
   SET count = count +1 
   WHERE id = NEW.id;
END//
```

After change it back

```
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

forget `;` at end of line

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_entry 
AFTER UPDATE ON entry FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE entry SET count = count +1 WHERE id = NEW.id;//forget to close line ;
END;//
delimiter;
```

[Mysql Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: I have to use this from CLI so if I put that semicolumn at the end ot NEW.id it finishes the query